# Spring rest internationalization is returning 500 http status

Tags: spring, rest, internationalization, spring-rest

I'm learning Spring via an Udemy course. I have reached a point where the topic is internationalization, which is useful for me and my current job.
After configuring the code just like the course, when I request to localhost:8080/hello_world_internationalized i get the following JSON as a response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-10-03T14:27:27.765+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "No message found under code 'good.morning.message' for locale 'en'.",
    "path": "/hello_world_internationalized"
}
```

This is the code of the configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver localeResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return localeResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource bundleMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("app_messages");      
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class HelloWorldController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @GetMapping(path = "/hello_world_internationalized")
    public String helloWorldInternationalized() {
        return messageSource.getMessage("good.morning.message", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
    }
}
```

I have scoured the internet and found some topics talking about a < bean > tag that contains the configuration for the internationalization to work.

But I don't know where to put this configuration tag. As I am trying to create a Rest service so i'm using web, rest services and devtools as dependencias on my project. Also i'm using HATEOAS.
Also I noticed that I don't have the WEB-INF folder and the web.xml file which aparently are needed to configure these things. Where can I create these folders and files?

Comment: Remove the `LocaleResolver`, remove the `MessageSource`. Set the `spring.messages.basename=app_messages` in your `application.properties` and make sure it exists in `src/main/resources` restart your application. Or rename your `app_messages.properties` to `messages.properties` and use the Spring Boot defaults and just restart.

Comment: That worked. So the two beans that I created were impeding the use of internationalization Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you created  **app_messages_en.properties**(The file for the en locale ) and **app_messages.properties**(The file for the default locale ) file in resources path **(src/main/resources)**
also add key value in this file

```
good.morning.message=value of this key
```

The keys for the values that will be localized have to be the same in every file, with values appropriate to the language they correspond to.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like server caching issue, where it is not able to read the properties file. (Not sure though)

I have resolved this issue by enabling the DEBUG in the application.properties file and restarting the server. 
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG

It started picking the changes.